# Example of what's an example of $f_n,f\in L^1(\mathbb{R},L,m)$ with some properties

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

what's an example of $f_n,f\in L^1(\mathbb{R},L,m)$ with $||f_n-f||\to 0$ and $f(x)> 0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, while for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ the set $\{x \in\mathbb{R} | f_n(x) < 0\}$ has positive Lebesgue measure.

First I can't come up with an example of $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R},L,m)$ with $f(x)> 0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f = \min \{1, 1/|x|^2\}$. Let $f_n = f - 2 \chi_{[-1/n, 1/n]}$.
Then $f-f_n = \chi_{[-1/n, 1/n]}$.